# How to execute a script with using a keyword

Tags: linux, bash

I have a requirement, where I have my linux script which does my work. But I want to use a simple keyword to execute my script file and get the output.

example:
`sudo save`

The above command should execute my script file which is saved as abc.sh

How to do it in linux or mac. Please help

Comment: you can create an `alias` with name `save` and can use that alias to execute the script, [to create an alias in Linux](https://www.tecmint.com/create-alias-in-linux/)

Comment: thanq, i am able to fix it now with alias